# How to add a colons (:) between inline list elements?

Tags: css

Is there anyway to add colons between inline list elements?

Example:

> home : blog : contact

Comment: Those are dots, not dashes. The symbol itself is also known as a [colon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) and `content`:

```
/* add : after each li */
#ul li:after{
  content:":"
}  

/* remove from last one */
#ul li:last-child:after{
  content:""
}
```

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ugivod/2)

Comment: You need to remove it for `li:last-child`, or if you need IE8 compatibility, reverse it using `:first-child` and `:before` instead. Works either way, but you may have to style it differently to get it to look correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is just # more in your answer.

Comment: @DexyOnline: It is fixed now, please see example again.

Answer (score 1):

The proper ways would be these

```
ul li:not(:last-child):after{
  content:":"
}
```

Comment: That will still add `:` to the last element, try it out

Comment: Probably because he forgot to add a `:` to `last-child`. Using `:not()` should also work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one rule only, adding `:` before, starting from the second element.

```
li + li:before {
  content  : ":";
  /* add padding around */
}
```